# Use Vue JS to make default selection(s) within Array

Tags: arrays, vue.js, statamic

I see a lot of questions on Stack Overflow dealing with Vue JS and selecting a default *single* value from an Array. I, however, need to compare each item's array `groups` to an array of ALL THE GROUPS `ensemble_groups`, and load the correct selections by default.

Here's how I'm trying to do this now:

```
<div id="oven">
    <template v-for="biscuit in oven">
            <!--show checkbox for every available group-->
            <!--check groups array to see if this ensemble_group should be selected by default-->
            {{ ensemble_groups }} 
              <input type="checkbox"
                name="cast_list[@{{ $index }}][groups][]"
                :checked="biscuit.groups.IndexOf(name) == {{ group_name }}"
                value="{{ group_name }}"
                      id="g-@{{ $index }}-{{ group_name|slugify }}">
              <label for="g-@{{ $index }}-{{ group_name|slugify }}">{{ group_name }}</label>
              <br>
            {{ /ensemble_groups }}
    </template>
</div>
```

So I've got my ALL THE GROUPS values stored in YAML as `ensemble_groups.group_name`

which match up to predefined values stored in YAML as `cast_list.groups.value`

and my Vue.js array is storing them as `oven.groups.name` like so:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#oven',

  data: {
    oven: [
      {{ cast_list }}
        {
          groups: [
            {{ groups }}
              {
                name: "{{ value }}"
              },
            {{ /groups }}
          ],
        },
      {{ /cast_list }}
    ]
  }
})
```

Am I even making sense? I'm comparing the arrays (multiple predefined vs. all available).

So if I have 4 ensemble_groups values like `["Ballroom dancers", "Tap dancers", "Farmers", "Cowboys"]` and a cast_list entry is put into two groups `["Tap dancers", "Cowboys"]`, I want the checkboxes for those two groups to be checked when the page loads.

Help?

**UPDATE:**

I've used Roy's Answer to get the checkboxes working, but I've lost the index value to keep the data in the right place. Continued over at [How to set incremental counter for nested arrays using Vue JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644187/how-to-set-incremental-counter-for-nested-arrays-using-vue-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Multiple checkboxes can be bound to an array](https://vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#Checkbox) to work the way you want. The snippet below lists the `ensemble_groups` with checkboxes beside them. Below that, the `cast_groups` array is listed. The `cast_groups` array starts out with one value, but a timer programmatically adds one, then removes the first one so you can see it responding to data changes. You can also click the checkboxes to toggle membership, and the `cast_groups` will be changed accordingly.

```js
const v = new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: {
    ensemble_groups: ["Ballroom dancers", "Tap dancers", "Farmers", "Cowboys"],
    cast_groups: ['Tap dancers']
  }
});

setTimeout(() => {
  v.cast_groups.push('Farmers');
}, 2000);

setTimeout(() => {
  v.cast_groups.$remove('Tap dancers');
}, 3500);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<div v-for="group in ensemble_groups">
  <input type="checkbox" value="{{group}}" v-model="cast_groups">{{group}}
</div>
<ul>
  <li v-for="group in cast_groups">{{group}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited my OP with my new code, because once I adapted your solution for my scenario (keeping my data structure intact), I've lost the ability to use `@{{ $index }}` because it's stuck in the `ensemble_groups` loop, cycling through `0,1,2,3` over and over. I need an incremental index that's attached to `v-for="member in cast"` and I tried `@{{ member.$index }}` and `@{{ $member.index }}` but neither works.

Comment: @danfo If your only reason for the `id` is to tie the labels to the inputs, I'd just put the inputs inside the labels and forget the `id`s.

Comment: It's to keep the data structure intact for my array upon save, which must follow the structure `array_name[0][field_name]`, `array_name[1][field_name]`, `array_name[2][field_name]`, etc.

Comment: Post a new question with some information about your save process. It seems like the id should be part of the data item and not just a view issue.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the attention.